# database to use for Automated Teller Machine

Tags: database-recommendation

I have been working on an **Automated Teller Machine** project using **Visual Studio** and **C#** for my Bachelors Degree project.

Which database platform should I use for this?  I'm considering MySQL, but am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For projects using Visual Studio, I'd almost invariably recommend using [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx).  The product is free to use, as long as you can live with the limitations: Microsoft SQL Server Express supports 1 physical processor, 1 GB memory, and 10 GB relational storage.  I'd expect for an ATM project you won't be locally storing a lot of data, so that shouldn't be a concern.